# How to implement a custom dynamic interceptor?

Tags: c#, .net, expandoobject

I'm trying to think of a way to utilize a dynamic type to provide for natural usage of its members but it ultimately sourced from a `Dictionary<string, string>` object. However, I want to be able to define the rules for how a given property is resolved. Is this possible?

I want something like so.

```
var dynamicCollection = new MyDyanmicType();
dynamicCollection.Build(/*some dictionary*/); // or just implement an implicit operator
dynamicCollection.MemberProperty; // <-- this should let me search the dictionary how I want for some form of the string "MemberProperty"
dynamicCollection.PropertyThatDoesntExist; // <-- this should give me an opportunity to exhaust my resolution and throw back a custom exception that I choose
```

The use case is I have some fields that are dynamically setup in a database by product management personnel. Unfortunately, I need to guard against the volatility of human error. Given the above, someone might enter memberProperty, Member Property, etc. so I need to control how a declared member is looked up while maintaining a clean usage of a normal POCO.

The problem I'm facing is I have a TON of boilerplate dictionary code I'm trying to get rid of and this would allow me to get rid of some rather nasty and verbose runtime checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was drastically easier than I thought. The solution looks like so.

```
public class AddOnBag : DynamicObject
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _addOns;

    public static AddOnBag BuildBag(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
    {
        var bag = new AddOnBag {_addOns = dict};

        return bag;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        var addOn = LookupAddOn(binder.Name);

        result = addOn.Value;

        return addOn.Key != null;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        var addOn = LookupAddOn(binder.Name);

        if (addOn.Key == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        _addOns[addOn.Key] = value.ToString();

        return true;
    }

    private KeyValuePair<string, string> LookupAddOn(string name)
    {
        var addOn = _addOns.FirstOrDefault(pair =>
        {
            var stripped = pair.Key.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
            var attempted = name;

            return string.Equals(stripped, attempted, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        });

        return addOn;
    }
}
```

Also, as it turns out, Microsoft provides an example very close to this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/walkthrough-creating-and-using-dynamic-objects

Usage just requires the `dynamic` keyword. Plus, if you add a method to the class you create, the CLR is intelligent enough to route the call to the intended method rather than `TryGetMember` or `TryInvokeMember`.